# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67 cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

When I start the jboss-4.0.3SP1 with EJB Services it is getting following error log time to time. Once issue came and then restart issue will resolved. Need to find why this issue happen time to time when we start the EJB application inside the Jboss application server.

Error Log:-

```
2019-10-21 10:17:18,755 INFO  [STDOUT] Getting Initial context
2019-10-21 10:17:18,755 INFO  [STDOUT] Getting bonotel-cancellation-serviceEjbServices
2019-10-21 10:17:18,808 INFO  [STDOUT] Getting bonotel-cancellation-serviceEjbServices Home
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT] java.lang.ClassCastException
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:150)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at rez.services.connectorservices.ServiceObjectFactory.getService(ServiceObjectFactory.java:127)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at rezg.admin.web.base.common.JobSchedulerServlet.activateDefaultLoadersImpl(JobSchedulerServlet.java:494)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at rezg.admin.web.base.common.JobSchedulerServlet.init(JobSchedulerServlet.java:189)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:925)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3857)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4118)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,822 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5005)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:150)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:280)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:88)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:357)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:68)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:46)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:274)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:230)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:943)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:428)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:400)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.start(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:989)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:979)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:790)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:753)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,823 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:319)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:507)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:192)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:265)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:274)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:230)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:943)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:428)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:285)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:989)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:790)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:753)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:737)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:453)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:330)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:187)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:438)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,824 INFO  [STDOUT]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-10-21 10:17:18,825 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67 cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
2019-10-21 10:17:18,825 INFO  [STDOUT]  at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:228)
```

I have added my ServiceObjectFactory.java class, line 127 with comment for your further reference.

Java Source Code:-

```
public static RezService getService(String host,String port, String portalName) throws RezException {

        System.out.println("Discover port and host automatically...");

        try {
            host = AutomaticJbossPropertyDiscovery.discoverProperty("jboss:service=Naming", "BindAddress");
            port = AutomaticJbossPropertyDiscovery.discoverProperty("jboss:service=Naming", "Port");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
             System.out.println("Failed automatic discovery of port and host" + e1.getMessage());
       }        

        RezService service = null;

        try {
            // Get a naming context            
            Hashtable props = new Hashtable();      
            props.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            props.put("java.naming.provider.url", host+":"+port);

            // Lookup the EJB
            InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);
            Object ref  = jndiContext.lookup(portalName+"EjbServices");         

            // Get a reference from this to the bean's Home interface

            RezServiceHome home = (RezServiceHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref, RezServiceHome.class);// line 127   
            service = home.create();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
            throw new RezException(e.getMessage());
        }        
        return service;
}
```

Comment: Are you redeploying your application between server restarts?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No. This issue came at the first restart time. After issue came jboss not started properly. Then I restarted again. At that time may fixed above issue.

Comment: I think that `com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject` in the stack trace is odd because JBoss uses JacORB for its CORBA implementation right up until the early WildFly releases.

Comment: I am assuming that you are deploying an EAR file? Is it possible that the EAR contains multiple copies of the `RezServiceHome` class file?

Comment: I have updated the question with full stack trace for your further reference.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a consequence of having your class `RezServiceHome` included in two or more separate jars in your classpath.

Add `-verbose:class` to your Java options, restart the server and search for your class. If your EJB jar contains this class, you should remove it along with all other duplicated classes (frequently those would be: `RezServiceHome`, `RezServiceBusiness` and `RezService`). They should be in one of APP-INF/lib jar files within your ear file.